# Having child route use parent props in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have a React app with a detailed site about jobs that let's the user create, edit and view all jobs.

From the view all jobs table the user is able to go see details about one job which routes to the path jobs/:id

```
<Link to={{ pathname: `/jobs/${props.id}` }}>View</Link>
```

This view is going to reuse a lot of the computed properties from the main jobs Component. Is there a way I can pass the props from the main jobs component down to the jobs/:id path?

One option I can think of is to provide it in the Link above but that would not work when the user directly types in the route in the url.

I have my routes defined in the main App.js file

```
 <Router>
    <ResponsiveDrawer>
      <div className="App">
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Administrator} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Administrator} />
            <Route exact path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
            <Route path="/jobs/:id" render={({match}) => <ViewJob id={match.params.id} />} />
            <Route path="/reports" component={Reports} />
          </div>
      </div>
     </ResponsiveDrawer>
 </Router>
```

Comment: Why not let the Jobs component decide wether it should show all jobs or the specific job?

Comment: In that case how would I be able to allow users to access the specific job through the url /jobs/:id as well?

Comment: May be use a common reducer state, which gets updated on componentDidMount() of both jobs listing and detail page. So any state change will re-render and you can also structure the page with common properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method instead of render Viewjob in your routes

```
    const viewjob = ({match}) => (
            <h>{match.params.id}</h>
)
export default viewjob
```

and just put a console.log in this viewjob component for get the detail of match parameter

```
    const Catgeory = ({match}) => console.log('match parameteres is : ' , match )(
            <h>{match.params.id}</h>
)
export default Catgeory
```